# PHP - How to use the sum variable inside a loop

Tags: php

I just wanted to get the sum of integers inside my `foreach` loop.
Typically we can get the sum by this kind of syntax

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($group as $key=>$value)
{
   $sum+= $value;
}
echo $sum;
```

by `echoing` the `$sum` variable we can get the sum outside of the loop.

But I wanted to use the `$sum` variable inside the `foreach` loop.
I'm having some computation in my program. And I need use the `$sum` variable inside the loop itself.

here are the values inside `$sum`

```
1260.32871
9689.77324
10760.87267
126247.29657
151455.92761
198485.57421
223694.20525
334296.14836
348160.79259
352887.41091
367760.42095
466451.71783
471178.33615
471966.10587
473856.85604
475416.45497
```

The sum is `475416.45497` which is of course at the last. the thing is I'm having computation inside the loop. Since it's iterating. I can still get the previous values starting from the top `1260.32871` while having my computation. I just wanted to get the `475416.45497` which is at the very bottom.

Comment: _"But I wanted to use the `$sum` variable inside the `foreach` loop."_ So what's stopping you?

Comment: You can `echo` the sum inside the loop. It will give the updated value every iteration.

Comment: Why do you think you can't use it inside the loop as well? Of course, it will only have the sum so far, not the final value.

Comment: I briefly explain my post. I edited the question. thanks

Comment: Try this: array_sum($group);. It will give you sum of all the values inside $group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the total sum of your $value inside the loop, you must first calculate it, before entering the loop:

```
$sum = array_sum(array_column($group, 'column_key'));
```

where `'column_key'` is the index of the array `$group` containing the values you want to sum.

Example:

Let's say that we have this array containing values to sum:

```
$data = [
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Jhon',
        'salary' => 1500
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'Jane',
        'salary' => 2000
    ]  
];
```

Now we want the sum of all salaries:

```
$totSalary = array_sum(array_column($data, 'salary'));
// echo $totSalary will print 3500
```

Answer (score 1):

Logically, you can't. You are using the `foreach` loop to *calculate* the sum, so you can't have the complete sum *inside* the loop. There are two other ways I can think of you could solve this problem, if you need to:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($group as $key=>$value)
{
    $sum+= $value;
}
echo $sum;
foreach($group as $key=>$value)
{
    // the sum is now complete and can be used
}
```

Or:

```
$sum = array_sum($group);
echo $sum;
foreach($group as $key=>$value)
{
    // the sum is now complete and can be used
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not get total sum of integers inside loop. because of iteration. but you can get iterative sum result from this loop.

```
 $sum = 0;
 $group=['t'=>3,'m'=>4];
 foreach($group as $key=>$value)
 {
    $sum+= $value;
    echo $sum.'<br>';
 }
```